# $x,y,z$ are all strictly positive, $x+y+z=1$, what is $\max(xyz)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

$x,y,z$ are all strictly positive, $x+y+z=1$, what is $\max(xyz)$?

***My attempt:***

Using rand() function in Microsoft Excel to generate random numbers between $0$ and $1$. I used this function for the values of $x$ and $y$.

For the value of $z$, I used the formula $z=1-x-y$. This will make some values to be negative, which does not satisfy the condition given in the problem statement. However, repeating the process will lead us to find positive $z$ values.

Then I used max() function. I observed that the $\max(xyz)=0.03703...$

I am not sure if $0.03703...$ is really the maximum value of the product of $x,y,$ and $z$.

How to find the exact value (closed form) of $\max(xyz)$ without using programs?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $x,y,z>0$,$$xyz\leq\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3.$$
When does the equality hold?

Comment: I tried but I did not reach to anything. The problem is that I did not study Lagrange's Multiplier. Could you please help me to find $\max(xyz)$?

Comment: Do you mean that; since the arithmetic mean of three positive numbers is greater than or equal to their geometric mean; therefore $\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge (xyz)^\frac{1}{3}$, which implies that $\frac{1}{3} \ge (xyz)^\frac{1}{3}$, which implies that $xyz\le\frac{1}{27}$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Use the inequality I hinted to get $xyz\leq(\frac13)^3=\frac{1}{27}$. When $x=y=z=\frac13$, $xyz=\frac{1}{27}$, so $\max(xyz)=\frac{1}{27}$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Yes! That is what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint, aiming in the same direction as the answer from Feng Shao:

If you take $x,y,z$ to be the edges of a cuboid in 3d space, how can you maximize the volume of this guy when the sum of edge lengths are fixed? Can you prove that a cube (all sides have equal length) has the best ratio of volume to sum of side lengths?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that I can come up with.

1. By using the AM-GM inequality, you have

$$\sqrt [3]{xyz} \leq \frac{x+y+z}{3},$$

for non-negative $x$, $y$, and $z$.

2. As you attempted, represent $z$ with $x$ and $y$, and compute partial derivatives of $xyz$ with $z$ being replaced by $1-x-y$, and check if the critical points are in the domain and the signs of second partial derivatives.
3. The method of Lagrange multipliers:
   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: For the first one you need $x+y+z$ rather than $xyz$

Comment: asdf, you are right. That is a typo, but thank you for letting me know.